# F# seq.skipWhile not having expected behavior (skipping the whole sequence)

Tags: .net, parsing, f#

I am writing a program that compares the content of a remote file and logs in real time (versus downloading the file and replacing it each time with the newest "version" of it) it's content to a local file. In order to do that, I create an FTP connection, read the remote file, skip everything up to the last line read, and copy all the new lines into the local file.

In order to do the comparison between what is new or not, I use the following function:

```
let getNewLines (lineToLookFor:string) (varLogLines:seq<string>) =
    let newLines = Seq.skipWhile ((fun (lineToMatch:string) (varLogLine:string) -> not(lineToMatch.Equals(varLogLine))) lineToLookFor) varLogLines
    match Seq.length newLines with
    | 0 -> (varLogLines, lineToLookFor)  // There has been a rollover of the messages file, take all the lines as they are all new
    | _ -> (newLines, Seq.last newLines) // Only take the new lines which were written since the last check in the messages file
```

Seq.skipWhile is supposed to skip all entries in a seq for which the predicate function returns true, and then return the rest of the seq. In my case, I want to read all line up until lineToMatch.Equals(varLogLine) and then return everything else after that point in the seq.

Unfortunately, newLines is always empty, thus the flow of my program always goes in the first match | 0 ->. I can't figure out why.

For the record, I have also tried Contains instead of Equals without any success.

Comment: Your code looks fine (e.g. the result of `getNewLines "x" [for c in 'a' .. 'z' -> string c]` is as expected).  Perhaps your `lineToLookFor` ends with a carriage return or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the function inside the `Seq.skipWhile` with the following:

```
let getNewLines (lineToLookFor:string) (varLogLines:seq<string>) =
    let newLines = Seq.skipWhile (fun varLogLine -> varLogLine <> linetoLookFor) varLogLines
    match Seq.length newLines with
    | 0 -> (varLogLines, lineToLookFor)  // There has been a rollover of the messages file, take all the lines as they are all new
    | _ -> (newLines, Seq.last newLines) // Only take the new lines which were written since the last check in the messages file
```

Alternatively, if all you want is "all lines after the one I'm looking for", you could do this:

```
let getNewLines (lineToLookFor:string) (varLogLines:seq<string>) =
    let maybeIndex = Seq.tryFindIndex (fun line -> line = lineToLookFor) varLogLines
    match maybeIndex with
    | Some index -> Seq.skip (index + 1) varLogLines // return the elements after the one you provided
    | None -> varLogLines // return all elements.
```

You can then take the result of that function and store the last entry for use later - you used to do it inside getNewLines, but I feel it's cleaner to let the caller handle that job:

```
let newLines = getNewLines lastLine varLogLines
let newLastLine = Seq.last newLines
```

EDIT: Looks like you're returning the original `lineToLookFor` when there's no match - it feels like you should be returning `Seq.last lineToLookFor` instead.

Also, if you're using CCR and can avoid making this specific function use it, I'd definitely avoid it. The function is simple enough that I don't think you need to wrap it inside a `ccr { }` block, and I've been bitten by CCR before for things that look like they should work fine but end up not doing so.

Comment: I am having the same issue with your alternative code unfortunately.

Comment: @Choub890 Are you relying on the fact that this is a `seq<string>` as opposed to another, non-lazy type? I don't see any issue when building a seq from a list, but things might go differently if the Seq is actually an IEnumerable<string> that you can't enumerate more than once.

Comment: varLogLines is a seq<string> created of an array of string using seq.ofArray. Am I missing something related to sequences created by an array vs a list vs something else?

Comment: @Choub890 No, that should be fine. An array of strings is a seq<array> too, anyway, so you could just pass it into the function as is. Have you looked at the parameters to your function in the debugger to see if the data you're passing in is actually the data you're expecting?

Comment: Yeah I've checked for the first 20-30 or so items and they seem to be exactly what I expect. The only other thing I am starting to suspect is our use of ccr and my code being done in an asynchronous way. The caller function is actually getting spawned asynchronously with ccr, and I'm starting to think this has an impact on getNewLines ?

Comment: AFAIK, it shouldn't have any impact - your function is pure, so its result shouldn't depend on its execution environment. Using the version of getNewLines that I suggested (the one with `Seq.tryFindIndex`), can you check if the index is returned `Some index`? It kinda looks like you're searching for a string that's actually not in your varLogLines, as @kvb said. =/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105311/discussion-between-roujo-and-choub890).